# re-sizing of a scene in flash CC

Tags: flash

I have an animation scene in flash CC containing lot of objects(movie clips, buttons)with stage dimensions as 1000 x 550. Now I need the same scene in 800 x 600 stage dimensions. How can I change it to required size with all intermediate objects at a time? I have tried the same by using transform tool but failed to re-size all the objects. Please do suggest.

Comment: what do you mean by it failing "to re-size all the objects"?

Comment: might I also ask why you wish to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I wanted to resize the content with respect to the size. I found the solution for this. Here there is an option to do so . By changing the dimensions of required size in Stage size, we need to click the scale content check box. And it automatically changes the content size to fit in the stage.